# How to get rid of Xorg from Macports?

Tags: macports

I have installed some packages from macports, and nearly all of them required to install Xorg. How can I remove the Xorg packages? Is there a way to reinstall all my Xorg dependant package without Xorg support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ports have a +nox11 variant, which you can add as a default variant in the variants.conf file that's pointed to in your macports.conf file.  However, in my experience, there are some X11-dependent ports that don't have the +nox11 variant. I believe I've also seen situations in which non-X11-dependet port A depends on port B, and port B is so deeply X11-dependent that it wouldn't even make sense for it to have a +nox11 variant. Overall, in my experience, it's practically impossible to keep Xorg from getting installed. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to worry about xorg-* related ports. They provide the client libs for applications using X11 only. You can continue to use the X server shipped with OS X (or XQuartz).

See also the corresponding entry in the [MacPorts FAQ](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#x11-libs).

Answer (score 0):

To disable X11 variants by default, edit `/opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf` and add this line: `-x11 +no_x11 +quartz`.

If you install a port that requires X11 and doesn't offer a variant without, you'll have to live with it. But this will at least make it harder to accidentally install the X11 libraries when you don't want to.